# Broken graphics on some games

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, graphics, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

On my Samsung Galaxy Core Prime VE, running Android 5.1.1, the game's graphics are not displayed, but the sound plays. This happens as soon as the game starts.

What might be causing this and how can I correct it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you please include more information? On what games are these glitches orruring? Looks really frightening to me. Does it only happen after a certain amount of time or directly when you start a certain game?

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me every time I play Clash of clans with charging. But usually it happens after an hour of charging. So try to cool down the device. If this happens on starting the game then thanks for reading.

Comment: That is not working still same problem